# Four Trys to Start / Stop / Start MediaPlayer on Button Click Android Java

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

### GOAL: Start, Stop, then Start play of a sound by clicking button 3 times

Hello All

I am new to Android.
I have had trouble restarting the play of a sound after stopping it by click of a button.
I have researched this problem 
[( Link )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and found different methods to apply.
So, I have tried four ways (unsuccessfully) to do this.
There are four buttons which use different methods.
Button 1 will be used as a control.
Look to comments for results of different methods.
I will post a couple entries from LogCat below.

Thank You

---

[Here is a link to a relevant Android State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

---

### src/com.example.playsound/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.playsound;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public  class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Create Media Player
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button Sound
    final MediaPlayer mPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playsound0);
    final MediaPlayer mPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playsound1);
    final MediaPlayer mPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playsound2);
    final MediaPlayer mPlayer4 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playsound3);

    //Button References
    Button button1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);

    //Button 1 OnClickListener
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPlayer1.isPlaying() ) {
                try {
                    mPlayer1.stop();                    
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                                                 //   BUTTON 1
            else {                                //   plays sound upon first click, stops on second click
                try {                              //    but does not play on third click
                    mPlayer1.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }); 

    //Button 2 Uses .prepareAsync() 
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPlayer2.isPlaying() ) {            //  BUTTON 2
                try {                                // Plays sound upon first click, stops on second click
                    mPlayer2.stop();                  // But will not play upon third click
                    mPlayer2.reset();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    mPlayer2.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPlayer2.start();

            }

        }
    }); 


    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPlayer3.isPlaying() ) {
                try {                                  //  BUTTON 3
                    mPlayer3.stop();                    //  Does not play sound upon first button click
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                mPlayer3.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer3) {
                        mPlayer3.start();
                    }

                });
            }

        }
    }); 

    //Button 4 OnClickListener
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mPlayer4.isPlaying() ) {
                        try {
                            mPlayer4.stop();                    
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                                                         //   BUTTON 4
                    else {                                //   does not play sound on first click
                        try {
                            mPlayer4.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mPlayer4.start();
                    }

                }
            }); 

    }

}
```

---

Most errors in LogCat are similar to:

prepareAsync called in state 8

start called in state 0

start called in state 1

---

The errors are mostly "call in state #" errors.
I have referenced the diagram posted in the link above.
I still have these errors when I attempt to call methods in correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling methods in unappropriate states.

PrepareAsync can be called in only {Initialized, Stopped} state.

Start can be called only in {Prepared, Started, Paused, PlaybackCompleted} states.

So if you try to call those in other states than those then it will throw exception.

To have a clear knowledge about the states read this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)